# How can manually trigger a tooltip over and input box from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web form and on it I have two input boxes.  When the onkeypress event is triggered in box A, I want a tooltip to appear over box B.

I am firing a javascript function from the onkeypress event in box A which should show the tooltip over box B.

Should be simple but I can't get the thing to work.  Any ideas?

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ej22rueo/7/)...

**Html**

```
Input here: <input id="boxA" type="text" onkeypress="PopulatePrice()" />
<br/>
<br/>
Tooltip to appear here: <input id="boxB" title="blah" type="text" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#boxB').tooltip({
        $(this).tooltip({
        content: 'some stuff',
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement:'top',
        html: true
    });
});

function PopulatePrice(){
$('#boxB').tooltip('show');
}
```

Comment: which tooltip library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ej22rueo/2/)

Change your JS as below

```
$('#boxB').tooltip({
  content: 'some stuff',
  trigger: 'manual',
  placement: 'top',
  html: true
});

function PopulatePrice() {
  $('#boxB').tooltip('show');
}
```

Your JS wasn't working because you were getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this` on the line `$(this).tooltip({`.

Comment: Hey @PipecockJackson , could you please mark the answer as accepted if that really helped you..

Comment: Sure, stackoverflow makes you wait 15mins before you can indicate and answer